# "in-out debate is more nuanced than a lot of people would have us believe"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Could you explain what  the highlighted sentence means please? I am confused more on the word nuanced and `people would have us believe`

> Earlier on Monday, British Chambers of Commerce director general John
>   Longworth told the BBC that an in-out referendum should "take place as
>   soon as is practical".
>
> Mr Longworth said that 55% of his members were in favour of a
>   "reformed Europe", and said the **"in-out debate is more nuanced than
>   a lot of people would have us believe"**.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the debate in question has more subtleties.

As regards the:

> would have us believe

Here is the [causal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/have) use of have, definition #8 from American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language.

So it may read:

> would cause us believe.

Comment: Thank you.I do not get the word nuanced very well Can we translate this sentence like `in-out debate is not simple debate as it is seen or looked and may cause significant effects`

Comment: The in-out debate has more nuances (subtleties) than a lot of people would have (cause) us believe.

Answer (score 0):

I would say `more than people would have us believe` means `more than people want us to believe` or - even better - `more than people are trying to make us believe`.

The idea is that a lot of people involved in this debate are actively trying to make us (their audience) believe that the debate is really very simple. But it's not. It's nuanced. It's more nuanced than a lot of people would have us believe.